# Corona SDK Easing outBounce

Tags: lua, coronasdk, transition, easing

I'm having a bit of trouble with Corona's transitions with easing.

Here is my code:

```
transitionTime = 120
transition.to( newDot, { time = transitionTime, y = newDot.destination_y, transition=easing.outBounce } )
```

Unfortunately, it's not actually bouncing at all. It just seems to be moving normally. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if something else needs to be done before the easing transition will display.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that transition API never worked properly. What I always would do is make 2 transitions with one having a slight delay like so:

```
transition.to(newDot, {time=80,y = newDot.destination_y - 50})
transition.to(newDot, {delay=80, time=40, y=newDot.destination_y})
```

Just work with something like that so just change up the numbers to your liking. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you again Ninja Pig Studios! You've done it again :D I just had to use a + 50, instead; for anyone else who might find this!

Comment: No problem, but just remember when you become rich don't forget about me <3

Comment: Deal! I'll definitely remember you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using old corona version.The easing properties inBounce, outBounce, inOutBounce, outInBounce are applied only in new versions of corona. These properties will not work in old one.

Comment: I'm using the most recent version available without a subscription. Not sure if these easing properties are included in that version or not :\